# Close navbar dropdown with CSS on click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a third party theme in my project, which is based on Bootstrap, but does not seem to use the Bootstrap navbar.

The dropdown in the navbar shows on hover, and in the demo, the entire page reloads when an item is clicked, closing the navbar.
In my project I am using angular routing and templating, so the entire page is not reloaded and the navbar stays open until the cursor moves away from it.

There does not seem to be any Javascript involved, it's mostly done using CSS. This is a sample of the html and styling:

```
<ul class="navigation-menu">
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="">Setup</a>
         <ul class="submenu">
             <li><a href="#/setup/foo">Foo</a></li>
             <li><a href="#/setup/bar">Bar</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I think it's the visibility and opacity styling that's important:

```
.navigation-menu > li .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.navigation-menu > li.has-submenu:hover > .submenu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

So I tried a fix with jQuery where I change the visiblity, and reset it after a timeout:

```
$(document).on('click', '.submenu', function () {
    var submenu = this;
    $(submenu).css('visibility','hidden');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(submenu).removeAttr('style')
    }, 2000);
});
```

It seems to work, but if the cursor does not move at all, the dropdown shows up again after the timeout.

Is there any better way to fix this?

UPDATE: added a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2r0up3no/

It's odd, my "fix" works in Chrome and Firefox on Windows, but when I use it on Firefox on Ubuntu, it doesn't work.

Comment: anyway you could create a fiddle for us?

Comment: Added, although my fix does not consistently fail.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow at least for me, so I have the fiddle open.. now what is the problem *exactly*?

Comment: It's a minor UX issue really, but one I've been trying to fix for a while now and it's getting annoying. If you remove the javascript in the fiddle, the dropdown does not close on click, and I want it to close on click.

Comment: The other problem, but one I can't reproduce consistently in the fiddle, is that using the fix in the javascript does not work very nicely. Sometimes the dropdown will pop up again after the javascript timeout.

Comment: so then why don't you just hide the dropdown entirely until the 'Setup' is clicked again?

Comment: Setup should not need to be clicked, the dropdown shows on hover. That's why I remove the styling I apply in the jQuery, after a timeout.